# extract objects in pdf, copy and separate pdf objects based on color in itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a pdf file as attachment, the file has many objects inside like text, path, line etc. These objects can have different colors, I want to copy all these objects into multiple copies stars, where the color of all objects is converted to CMYK black.
[pdf source file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TDC98wvte7ufKRbDVTIRmgZd63RxM0Dc/view?usp=sharing)
[source file fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3cF8.png)

If the objects in the original file have many colors, then you need to separate each object into copies as shown and change it to CMYK black, if there is only black in the file, just copy the objects and convert them all to CMYK black. The desired result is illustrated as shown in Fig.
[expexted result fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shbHb.png)
[pdf expected result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/177VfJYDWll14jldGRqA9IuvCrIrdp7ZD/view?usp=sharing)

Can someone provide me some c# pseudocode?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean, can you explain more or give some c# pseudocode @KJ

Comment: If I don't care about color, could you help me anyway to copy all objects in pdf then paste them in new file pdf using c# as my details above?

Comment: Hi @mkl, could you help me to solve my problem ?

Comment: how do you extract pdf as result above ?

Comment: *"the file has many objects inside like text, path, line, ... these objects can have different colors, I want to copy all these objects into multiple copies"* - Shall that work only for files like your provided example file? Or shall it work for arbitrary files? In the latter case there may be shades (resulting in infinitely many output pages) and colors that cannot be represented in CMYK. Furthermore, in the original an item in one color might cover another item in another color; would you expect the formerly hidden item on the page of its color or shall it not appear in the result? Etc...